# Elastic search with CouchDB river plugin - Can't find any documents

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I recently started using elasticsearch and couchdb and I have the following problem. I have a couch database with a bunch of documents. I add a couchDb river index on elasticsearch and I expect to have those documents indexed and searchable. But when I search for anything though ES I don't get any results. The command flow is as follows:

The command above verifies that there are 4 documents in the couchDb instance

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:5984/my_db
```

result:

```
{
  "db_name": "my_db",
  "doc_count": 4,
  "doc_del_count": 0,
  "update_seq": 4,
  "purge_seq": 0,
  "compact_running": false,
  "disk_size": 16482,
  "data_size": 646,
  "instance_start_time": "1370204643908592",
  "disk_format_version": 6,
  "committed_update_seq": 4
}
```

The `_changes` output:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:5984/my_db/_changes
{
  "results": [
    {
      "seq": 1,
      "id": "1",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-40d928a959dd52d183ab7c413fabca92"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seq": 2,
      "id": "2",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-42212757a56b240f5205266b1969e890"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seq": 3,
      "id": "3",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-f59c2ae7acacb68d9414be05d56ed33a"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seq": 4,
      "id": "4",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-e86cf1c287c16906e81d901365b9bf98"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "last_seq": 4
}
```

Now, below I m creating my index in ES.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/my_db/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "couchdb",
  "couchdb": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5984,
    "db": "my_db",
    "filter": null
  }
}'

{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "my_db",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 1
}
```

But I don't get anything back.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_db/my_db/_search?pretty=true"
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : []
  }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you have a look at the elasticsearch log file?

Comment: Yeap - Log file doesn't really say much...

Comment: I had the same problem, I decided to go another direction, but you can easily create your own little app consuming the changes feed using follow https://github.com/iriscouch/follow and request https://github.com/request/request

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ElasticSearch index settings from your river metadata. From [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-couchdb):

```
{
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5984,
        "db" : "my_db",
        "filter" : null
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "my_db",
        "type" : "my_db",
        "bulk_size" : "100",
        "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
    }
}
```

I haven't seen any documentation that suggests the "index" member can be inferred.